# Computer in use or not?

Tags: java, networking, server, lan

I have project to develop a software where in a `LAN`,I have to find out how many systems are in use currently. I don't know where to start but I have a good knowledge in `JAVA`. Can someone give me from where to start and what are the resources required.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess when you mean 'system' in use you mean computers that are on? Or do you mean computers on the network that currently have uses logged on?

For the former you can scan the network, in Java there are a few scanners that can tell you what ip addresses there are connected to the network. There is NMap4j which seems to use nmap(the great network scanner) and parse the output, of course that requires nmap installed on the target machine. Or you can go for a pure Java/Scala implementation(flagrant self promotion here ;)) like https://github.com/michaelcouck/scanner, usage and examples on site.

Cheers...

Comment: I meant that computer which is currently switched on and in use.

Comment: I will check out the link and get back to you. Thanks ;)